# Pandas:set order of new generated column

Tags: pandas

I am working on a data  and write a code which will basically split the data of column (COL) with respect to (comma:,) and print the split data into new columns. Now, what I want is that my code is able to generate the new columns in given manner (desired output). The code is attached below. Thank you in advance.

**Input**

```
X1  COL Y1
----------------
A   X,Y,Z 146@12
B   Z   223@13
C   Y,X 725@14
```

Current output:

```
X1  Y1  COL-0   COL-1   COL-2
-----------------------------
A   146@12  X   Y   Z
B   223@13  Z   NaN NaN
C   725@14  Y   X   NaN
```

Desired output:

```
X1  COL-1   COL-2   COL-3   Y1
------------------------------
A   X   Y   Z   146@12
B   Z   -   -   223@13
C   Y   X   -   725@14
```

***Script***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r"<PATH TO YOUR CSV>")
for row, item in enumerate(df["COL"]):
    l = item.split(",")
    for idx, elem in enumerate(l):
        col = "COL-%s" % idx
        if col not in df.columns:
            df[col] = np.nan
        df[col][row] = elem

df = df.drop(columns=["COL"])

print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df['Y1'] = df.pop('Y1')
```

Also solution should be changed with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = (df.join(df.pop('COL').str.split(',', expand=True)
        .fillna('-')
        .rename(columns = lambda x: f'COL-{x+1}')))
df['Y1'] = df.pop('Y1')
print (df)
  X1 COL-1 COL-2 COL-3      Y1
0  A     X     Y     Z  146@12
1  B     Z     -     -  223@13
2  C     Y     X     -  725@14
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to replace the `NaN` values with dashes you can use  `fillna()` and, to keep the columns in order you specified you can simply define a dataframe with that column order.

`df_output = df[['X1','COL-1','COL-2','COL-3','Y1']].fillna(value='-')`

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant of methods, but this should handle your real data and intended result :

```
import re 

cols = df.filter(like='COL').columns.tolist()

pat = '(\w+)'

new_cols = [(f'{re.match(pat,col).group(0)} {i}') for i,col in enumerate(cols,1)]

df.rename(columns=dict(zip(cols,new_cols)),inplace=True)


df['Y1'] = df.pop('Y1')
out:
   X1 COL 1 COL 2 COL 3      Y1
0  A     X     Y     Z  146@12
1  B     Z   NaN   NaN  223@13
2  C     Y     X   NaN  725@14
```